# Given three positive numbers $a,b,c$. Prove that $\prod\limits_{sym}(\!a+\frac{1}{a}\!)\geqq\frac{4}{3}\sum\limits_{sym}\frac{b+c}{a}$ .

Tags: inequality, substitution, holder-inequality, discriminant, uvw

> Given three positive numbers $a, b, c$. Prove that $$\prod\limits_{sym}\left(\!a+ \frac{1}{a}\!\right)\geqq \frac{4}{3}\sum\limits_{sym}\frac{b+ c}{a}$$

I use *discriminant* and *uvw* and find it with the best constant $4\div 3$ .

*Titu lemma* and *Holder inequality* both are unsuccessful here, so I need to the help. Thanks a real lot

Comment: Please do not use displayed math in the title; this is the reason for the first edit and the rollback.

Comment: It's equivalent. $\geq$ or $\geqq$ each mean precisely the same thing.

Comment: What's the range on the product and sum??

Comment: a little further explanation please.

Comment: @HaiDangel Yes, $uvw$ kills it. If you want, I can show.

Comment: Maybe stop with the crazy edits in the title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to prove that
$$3\prod_{cyc}(a^2+1)\geq4\sum_{cyc}(a^2b+a^2c)$$ or
$$3(a^2b^2c^2+1)+3\sum_{cyc}(a^2b^2+a^2)\geq4\sum_{cyc}(a^2b+a^2c).$$
But by AM-GM
$$a^2b^2c^2+1\geq2abc.$$
Thus, it's enough to prove that
$$6abc+3\sum_{cyc}(a^2b^2+a^2)\geq4\sum_{cyc}(a^2b+a^2c).$$
Now, let $a+b+c=3u$, $ab+ac+bc=3v^2$ and $abc=w^3$.

Thus, we need to prove that:
$$6w^3+3(9v^4-6uw^3+9u^2-6v^2)\geq4(9uv^2-3w^3),$$ which is a linear inequality of $w^3$, which says that it's enough to prove the last inequality for an extreme value of $w^3$, which happens in the following cases.

1. $w^3\rightarrow0^+$.

Let $c\rightarrow0^+$.

Thus, we need to prove that
$$3a^2b^2+3a^2+3b^2\geq4(a^2b+ab^2),$$ which is true by AM-GM:
$$3a^2b^2+3a^2+3b^2=3\left(\frac{1}{2}a^2b^2+a^2+\frac{1}{2}a^2b^2+b^2\right)\geq$$
$$\geq3\left(2\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}a^2b^2\cdot a^2}+(2\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}a^2b^2\cdot b^2}\right)=3\sqrt2(a^2b+ab^2)>4(a^2b+ab^2);$$
2. Two variables are equal.

Let $b=a$.

Thus, we need to prove that
$$6a^2c+3(a^4+2a^2c^2+2a^2+c^2)\geq8(a^3+a^2c+ac^2)$$ or
$$(6a^2-8a+3)c^2-2a^2c+a^2(3a^2-8a+6)\geq0,$$ for which it's enough to prove that
$$(6a^2-8a+3)(3a^2-8a+6)\geq a^2$$ or
$$(a-1)^4\geq0$$ and we are done!

Comment: Why the fifth inequality is a linear inequality of w^3, then we can say that it's enough to prove the last inequality for an extreme value of w^3, which happens in the following cases? It is unclear for me.

Comment: @Word Shallow because $5=1\cdot3+2$. Also, see here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h278791

Comment: My question is why and when we have to check $w^3\rightarrow 0^+$ ? I've seen Hermitianism 's answer but sometimes i look into your answer it's not true.

Comment: @Word Shallow For example, if we need to prove that $f(w^3)\geq0$ for positive variables  and $f$ increases. We need to check two cases: 1. $w^3\rightarrow0^+$; 2. Two variables are equal.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3180945/an-inequality-with-the-constant-frac12-frac518-sqrt3 - Why you don't check this case?

Comment: @Word Shallow Because $w^3$ gets a maximal value for equality case of two variables only.

Comment: The last question for you. If i need to prove $f(w^3)=4v^2w^3-u^2w^3+9u^3v^2-12uv^4\ge 0$ see that $f$ is linear inequality then what should i do next?

Comment: @Word Shallow the sign of $4v^2-u^2$ is not defined, which says we need to check two cases.

Comment: Thank you very much, i got it now.